# How to Calculate and show the actual times where participants availability overlaps

Tags: php

How do I calculate and show the actual times where participants availability overlaps in a group. For example, this has 3 people and they have different availability.

Start Time - End Time

[person 1] => 1:30am - 5:00am

[person 1] => 5:00pm - 11:00pm

[person 2] => 12:00am - 11:30am

[person 3] => 2:00am - 11:30pm

this is other array

`Start Time`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1:30am
            [2] => 5:00pm                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 12:00am                
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2:00am                
        )

)
```

`End time`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5:00am
            [2] => 11:00pm                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 11:30am                
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 11:30pm                
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four cases when 2 timespan overlaps, and can be grouped in 2's:

```
// As, Ae = A start, A end
// Bs, Be = B start, B end

1) A  *-----*              -.
   B      *--------*        | As <= Bs && Ae >= Bs
                            }  = A starts before B
                            |    A ends during the span of B and can extend
2) A  *---------------*    -'      beyond B
   B      *--------*


3) A       *------*        -.
   B   *-------*            | Bs <= As && Be >= As
                            }  = B starts before A 
                            |    B ends during the span of A and can extend
4) A        *------*       -'      beyond A's duration
   B  *---------------*
```

Using this information, you can iterate through the schedules, compare if 2 schedule overlaps, if yes, compute the intersection of the two schedules. Then use this new intersected time as the basis for the next comparison in the loop (since you are looking for the ultimate intersection of all availability schedules).